# Can we define 2 counters of different types in a single for loop statement in C and increase them?

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement

Can we use `for` statement like that? (C programming language)

```
for(int i = 0,double j = 2; i != j+134; i++, j = j+17);
```

I'm trying to learn linked list and I try to increase the index and set the pointer to next node just by using a single `for`:

```
for(node* current,int i = 0; current!=NULL; current=current->next_node, i++);
```

Comment: Why dont you use a loop?

Comment: Yes and no... You can define multiple ones, but they need to be of the same type, just as with ordinary variable declarations: `for(int i = 0, j = 2; ;)`. For the condition and post-operation, you can indeed define arbitrary sequences, for the condition the last one must yield a value, though.

Comment: Are you sure don't mean a `for` construct??

Comment: You can create a scope around it all if you want to declare variables of different types. People often use a _function_ to do it.

Comment: Oh, just noticing – syntax drove me away from `if` – my previous comment applies to `for` loops – `if` cannot have anything more than a condition (*C++* allows a new form of `if` including definitions since C++17 – but that's not relevant here...).

Comment: @Aconcagua: Re “You can define multiple ones, but they need to be of the same type”: They need to be in one declaration, but they do not need to be the same type. `int x, *y, z[3]` can be in a `for` statement and declares objects of three different types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about?

```
struct IntDouble { int i; double j; };
for (struct IntDouble q = {0, 2}; q.i != q.j + 134; q.i++, q.j += 17) /* void */;
```

See code "running" at https://ideone.com/jEXBh7

Comment: Just having fun :)

Comment: Fewer statements, more fun: `for (struct { int i; double j; } q = { 0, 2 }; q.i != q.j + 134; q.i++, q.j += 17) {}`

Answer (score 2):

Opposite to C++ in C you may not declare objects in the if statement.

It seems you mean the for statement

```
for(int i = 0,double j = 2;i != j+134;i++ , j = j+17);
```

instead of the if statement

```
if(int i = 0,double j = 2;i != j+134;i++ , j = j+17);
```

However the syntax of this declaration

```
int i = 0,double j = 2;
```

is incorrect. You need to declare one of the variables before the for loop as for example

```
double j = 2;
for (int i = 0;i != j + 134; i++ , j += 17 );
```

If the type specifiers would be common for both variables i and j (for example the type int) then you could write

```
for (int i = 0, j = 2;i != j + 134; i++ , j += 17 );
```

The same approach should be used in this for loop where you forgot to initialize the pointer `current`

```
int i = 0;
for (node* current = head; current!=NULL; current=current->next_node,i++);
```

If you really mean to use the `if` statement then this line

```
if(node* current = head,int i = 0; current!=NULL; current=current->next_node,i++);
```

should be rewritten by you like

```
node *current = head;
int i = 0;

if ( current != NULL )
{
    current = current->next;
    i++;
}
```